# error seeing when parsing the json response using groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def testStepName = 'Adding_Users'

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = context.expand('$(testStepName#Response)')
def usersInfomration = jsonSlurper.parseText(response)
String userName = userInformation.name
log.info UserName
```

[image]

Comment: Means `context.expand('$(testStepName#Response)')` failed to expand value. Check that `testStepName` is valid. And as I remember it should be in curly brackets: `context.expand('${testStepName#Response}')`.

Comment: Thanks you .curly brackets works. But I am facing another error "text must not be null" at line 8

Comment: so your text is null. again: check the step name you using

Comment: as i can see by picture, th step name with rest has name `Adding_Users`. so, to access response from this step you have to use `'${Adding_Users#Response}'`